# Meeting request declined due to conflict for meeting room but graph api return response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am creating meeting room event using microsoft graph api. Now I am trying to book same meeting room for same time. Now it declined from outlook message but graph api gives response like it is created. Why it is not declining event response. The other issue is for this declined event, invitation has been sent to attendee. Why it is not responding with decline response?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Microsoft person like this :

> Meeting request from organizer side will be created and the invitation to other attendees will also be send. you are getting declined message back because the room resource is managed by the server and it will return the message based on the free/busy schedule and the event won't create in room resource calendar but it will created in the organizer and other attendees calendar.

Here meeting room is considered like other attendees and it is a default behavior that if one attendee declines the meeting it doesn't remove the organizers meeting request.